# About ATTINY85 Development Board

Tags: programming, usb, attiny85

I am thinking to buy one of "ATTINY85 Development Board"...

Before buying I was checking details/Advantages of it.

**First I thought this is just a breakout board & USB for power.**

**But, then found It can be programmed with "Digispark driver & board manager" directly by the USB.**

---

I checked this Question: [EBay “Development Programmer Board for ATtiny”](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/ebay-development-programmer-board-for-attiny)

Someone said there:

> "While limited, this type of board can be useful for "blink an LED on
>   USB command" type tasks"

---

My Main question is:

**Is it really programmable withut any TTL/ICSP/FTDI extention?**

**If so, is it possible to program other AVR chip (Attiny/Atmega) with simple codes directly via USB...?**

**(with same method)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it really programmable withut any TTL/ICSP/FTDI extention?

Only if you use an ATTiny chip that has the "Micronucleus" bootloader already installed.

> If so, is it possible to program other AVR chip (Attiny/Atmega) with simple codes directly via USB...?

Some can, but most need a bootloader installing. The ATMega32U4, for example, has a "DFU" mode, which is essentially a bootloader in ROM, that you can use directly over USB.  In general, though, the answer is "Not without installing an appropriate bootloader with some hardware programmer first".

Comment: Thanks... Now it makes sense... Because most of the tutorials doesn't told about "bootloader" part, maybe the soldered MC already has it... At last found a video with best review & tutorial [YT link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axagDO8AKSI)